# Repository Pattern: What is the 'right size'?

Tags: model-view-controller, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I'm building some repositories for an MVC application, and I'm trying to come up with the right way to divide responsibilities between repositories. In most cases, this is obvious. But there is one particular case where I'm not sure what the right answer is.

The users of this application need to track multiple types of time for their employees. For simplicity, let's consider only two. I'll call them "time cards" and "attendance." The exact nature of the difference between these two is not really important, but you should note that the end-users consider them entirely separate data. I think, though, that the reason they consider them entirely separate data is that they have never really had the opportunity to see them together in the past. Both types of records have almost entirely different business rules concerning editing the records, but they are also, generally speaking, both records of where an employee was at a particular time. Both types of time records have a great deal of properties in common, such as a total number of hours, and an employee for whom the time was collected. Both types also have a few properties which are completely unique to the individual type. We're keeping these "extra" properties in an instance of another type. So the general structure looks like this:

```
class TimeRecord 
{ 
    Person Employee { get; set; }
    TimeSpan? Hours { get; set; }
}

class TimeCardData
{
     TimeRecord Record { get; set; }
     TProperty TimeCardProperty  { get; set; }
}

class AttendanceData
{
     TimeRecord Record { get; set; }
     TProperty AttendanceProperty  { get; set; }
}
```

So the question is, **How many repositories are required here?**

### 1 Repository

A design with only one repository would expose methods to return "time cards", "attendance" records, or both types in one list. This is fairly convenient for clients of the repository, but, to my mind, has a real danger of becoming a very fat class. I think that a repository for just "time cards" is already going to be one of the largest repositories in the system even without also handling "attendance" simply due to the complex business rules involved.

### 2 Repositories

Another design would have one repository for "time cards" and another repository for "attendance" records. This has the advantage that the business rules for, e.g., "time cards" are in a place by themselves. But I'd also like to have a way to get a list of all time records, regardless of type. It's not clear which repository to use for this case. Both?

### 3 Repositories

A design with one repository for "time cards", another repository for "attendance" records, and a third repository to deliver a read-only list of all time records is also a possibility. Like the 2 repository design, this has the advantage that the business rules for, e.g., "time cards" are in a place by themselves. It's now clear where to get the combined list. But I find it a bit weird that I could get the same record from two different repositories.

### Hybrid

A hybrid approach would use a single repository, but move any business rules code (including selection of records) into separate types. In this example, a single "time record repository" would aggregate instances of business rule implementation classes for "time card" and "attendance" time. I think this is the approach I'm favoring right now.

### Other?

Anything I've missed? Any compelling arguments for one design over the other?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Repositories are, at least not to my knowledge, a place for business rules. They are just a facade meant to mimic a collection; underneath they're basically pure data access (if that's they're job, you may not be persisting anything with a Repository as well). So separate repositories should not be considered for "business rules" reasons.
2. If your domain objects are really separate objects, then you should have separate repositories. Remember what a repository is: it's a facade. It mimics a collection to your domain. See here for a really good blog post on Repositories: http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/20/ddd-the-repository-pattern.aspx

The repository is a facade; an abstraction.

That said... I do not think you have separate objects.  You've got some issues here that have nothing to do with repositories and everything to do with the domain and the design of the domain. Are the two types of "timecards" actually two different things, or are they really the same?

You say, *"But I find it a bit weird that I could get the same record from two different repositories."*

That tells me that they are actually the *same* data, expressed in different ways. And there are ways to handle that.

If this is really the case, then what you have here is subclasses of a common base class (something that can be modeled in a DB pretty easy and handled elegantly with NHibernate, for instance).

I'll give you an example of a project I am working on. I have something called a "Broadcast". It's a base class; abstract. Can't be instantiated. I have two specific concrete types of this class: DeviceBroadcast and FileBroadcast. One streams audio/video from a device (like a DirectX capture card) and one streams audio/video from a file source (like an .mp3).

I have one repository that returns a Broadcast object. I can cast it to a FileBroadcast to manipulate specific information about a FileBroadcast, or I can cast to a DeviceBroadcast for the same reason - if it is of that type. A Broadcast cannot be both a FileBroadcast and DeviceBroadcast type. It has to be one or the other.

In the database I store the generic broadcast parameters in a Broadcast table, and then I store the file specific properties in a FileBroadcast table. Same goes for the DeviceBroadcast table; separate. When I query via the Repository, however, I just want Broadcasts. That's my root aggregate object and thus that's my repository.

The Broadcast base class has common methods that both subclasses use (like the GetCommand() method, which returns a specific command-line argument to launch a VLC process). Subclasses have to override and implement that method because it's abstract. In this way, the "business logic" that is unique to a FileBroadcast is contained in the FileBroadcast class. The "business logic" that is unique to a DeviceBroadcast is contained in the DeviceBroadcast class. Any logic that is common to both is contained in the superclass, Broadcast.

You seem to have a similiar situation here and that's why I am sharing my design. I think it might serve you well.

Above all, think about your domain and the data. If you are going to get duplicate data by way of separate repositories, then you need to give more thought to how you're designing the domain. Don't let the users dictate your domain design either. They know the domain from their perspective. All you have to do is be able to present the data to them in a way they understand. That doesn't mean you have to have a bad design; You can have a good design behind the scenes because your code is the thing that has to use the domain.

Comment: I don't think the two types of time records are "separate objects," either. But my repositories, for better or worse, only return the instances that the user is allowed to see. Those selection rules are business rules. The hybrid design in the question moves them into separate types, however.

Comment: They can be separate types. That's fine. But don't let business rules dictate your repository design. You say the business rules dictate the queries; fine, let them. Doesn't mean you have to have separate repositories. Just query the one repository two different ways (detached query, or linq)

Comment: Take a look at Aggregates to group your repositories logically (not every entity gets a repository, only every Aggregate Root). Take a look at the Specification design pattern to move query-related business logic out of repositories and into the domain.